# VB code using advapi32.dll cryptverifysignature works on Vista SP2 not on Windows 10 64-bit

Tags: vba, api, encryption, vb6, cryptoapi

I have been trying to troubleshoot why an element of an application written and compiled in VB6 on a Vista SP2 machine works perfectly on that machine but not on a 64-bit Windows 10 machine. To improve debugging capabilities I replicated the problem coding in Excel VBA. Works on the Vista machine but not on the Windows 10 machine.

The CryptoAPI calls are all declared thusly:

```
Private Declare Function CryptVerifySignature _
Lib "advapi32.dll" _
    Alias "CryptVerifySignatureA" ( _
        ByVal hHash As Long, _
        pbSignature As Byte, _
        ByVal dwSigLen As Long, _
        ByVal hPubKey As Long, _
        ByVal sDescription As String, _
        ByVal dwFlags As Long _
            ) As Long
```

The part that is failing on the Windows 10 machine is highlighted by train tracks above and below in the following:

```
Private Function SignValidate(ByRef abData() As Byte, _
                        ByRef abSigned() As Byte, _
                        Optional bSigned As Boolean = True) As Long
Dim hHash As Long
Dim lngReturnValue As Long
Dim lngSigLen As Long
Dim abText() As Byte
Dim strTxt As String
Dim lngW As Long
Dim lngX As Long
Dim lngY As Long

Dim abHashVal() As Byte

SignValidate = -1
ReDim abText(UBound(abData))
abText = abData

'Create a hash object to sign/validate
lngReturnValue = CryptCreateHash(hCryptProv, CALG_SHA, 0, 0, hHash)
If lngReturnValue = 0 Then
    'Set_locale regionalSymbol
    Err.Raise Err.LastDllError, , "DLL error code shown above. Could not create a Hash Object (CryptCreateHash API)"
End If
'Hash the data
lngW = UBound(abText) + 1
lngReturnValue = CryptHashData(hHash, abText(0), lngW, 0)
If lngReturnValue = 0 Then
    'Set_locale regionalSymbol
    Err.Raise Err.LastDllError, , "DLL error code shown above. Could not calculate a Hash Value (CryptHashData API)"
End If

If bSigned Then
    'release old key pair handle
    If hKeyPair <> 0 Then CryptDestroyKey hKeyPair
    'get a handle to the signature key pair
    lngReturnValue = CryptGetUserKey(hCryptProv, AT_SIGNATURE, hKeyPair)
    If lngReturnValue = 0 Then
        'Set_locale regionalSymbol
        Err.Raise Err.LastDllError, , "DLL error code shown above. Could not obtain key pair"
    End If
    'Determine the size of the signature
    lngReturnValue = CryptSignHash(hHash, AT_SIGNATURE, 0, 0, vbNull, lngSigLength)
    If lngSigLength > 0 Then ReDim abSig(lngSigLength - 1)
    'Sign the hash object
    lngReturnValue = CryptSignHash(hHash, AT_SIGNATURE, 0, 0, abSig(0), lngSigLength)
    If lngReturnValue = 0 Then
        'Set_locale regionalSymbol
        Err.Raise Err.LastDllError, , "DLL error code shown above. Could not sign the hash"
    End If
    ' the signature is now available
    ' size returned array to signature length
    ReDim abSigned(UBound(abSig))
    ' return the signature to the calling procedure
    abSigned = abSig
    SignValidate = 0
Else
    lngSigLength = UBound(abSigned) + 1
    ReDim abSig(UBound(abSigned))
    abSig = abSigned ' load the Signature array

'========================================================
    'this is the line where the actual validation is done
    lngReturnValue = CryptVerifySignature(hHash, abSig(0), lngSigLength, hKeyPair, 0, 0)
'========================================================
    If lngReturnValue = 0 Then 'some error occurred
        SignValidate = Err.LastDllError
    Else
        SignValidate = 0
    End If
End If
End Function
```

The Windows 10 machine fails on the highlighted call to CryptVerifySignature and returns an Err.LastDllError equal to NTE_BAD_SIGNATURE. The Vista machine validates the signature fine.

I have spent days researching what might be happening here. All to no avail. Any pointers gratefully received

Comment: Is the Vista machine 64-bit?

Comment: You may need to use conditional compilation attributes. If you have a 64 bit version of office, the version of VBA is no longer VBA6, it's VBA7. Calling APIs/Functions are slightly different. See this article from MS. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ee691831(v=office.14).aspx

Comment: Thanks for your responses.  The Vista machine is 32 bit. Excel 2003 on Vista machine, 32-bit Excel 2016 on Windows 10 machine. I believe the line that fails in VBA is the same line that is failing in the compiled VB6 program where the call to CryptVerifySignature is in a custom DLL.

Comment: 32-bit types and 64-bit types are not equivalent. The call to CryptVerifySignature is not getting the parameters in the sizes it expects.

Comment: @Ryan I've had a look at the link and take 'Using the 32-bit version of Office 2010 enables you to use solutions built in previous versions of Microsoft Office without modification.' as confirmation that VBA version is not an issue.

Comment: Test your assumption. Use: #If VBA7 then MsgBox ("I'm Version 7!"), if you get the message box that tells you what version. Also Application.VBE.Version has that information too.

Comment: Did you look at using `PtrSafe` in your API declarations?

Comment: @dbugger Are you saying that I need to do some sort of conversion for the 64-bit machine? Can you point me to something that elaborates on the practical implications for pbSignature As Byte on a 64-bit system as opposed to a 32-bit system? I believe the pointer and the correct length are derived from a call to CryptSignHash. I thought, since it was coming from the same system, everything would be in sync. Please forgive my ignorance of these matters, your help is very much appreciated.

Comment: @Jim Hewitt Yes, PtrSafe made no difference.

Comment: One thing I noticed is that you use `lngSigLength` which isn't declared.  I do see `Dim lngSigLen As Long`.

Comment: @Ryan VBA version 7.01. Perhaps I should have given a fuller quote earlier. It was prefixed by **With the introduction of the new 64-bit version of Microsoft Office 2010, a new version of Microsoft Visual Basic for Applications (VBA), known as Microsoft Visual Basic for Applications 7.0 (VBA 7), is being released to work with both 32-bit and 64-bit applications. It is important to note that the changes addressed in this article apply only to the 64-bit version of Microsoft Office 2010.**  I concluded that, as I had 32-bit Excel, VBA 6 or 7 was all the same to me?

Comment: @Jim Hewitt Sorry, declared at module level. Thanks for pointing the redundant declaration out.

Comment: Not sure if I understand this function entirely (CryptVerifySignature), but you may need to change the return value from Long to LongPtr.

Comment: @Ryan From MSDN `Return value:If the function succeeds, the return value is TRUE.If the function fails, the return value is FALSE. ` Probably should be bool.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After much frustration and fruitless research I've eventually discovered what the problem was. Along the way I discovered that the problem originated in another part of the code altogether. I also discovered that the problem manifested itself on Windows 10 32 bit as well - so not a 64 bit problem.

An incorrectly populated dwflags argument to an earlier call to CryptImportKey didn't seem to prevent the call to CryptVerifySignature succeeding under Vista 32 bit, even though the call to CryptImportKey, on investigation, had failed. Once the dwflags argument of CryptImportKey was corrected, to CRYPT_EXPORTABLE Or CRYPT_NO_SALT, it succeeded and the subsequent call to CryptVerifySignature succeeded under all alternative operating system / bit number combinations I was able to test.

Apologies and thanks in equal measure to all those who have sought to help in this matter. Until the next time.

Answer (score 0):

> EDIT - I can't see anything wrong with your declare or call

The only alternative I've seen is to change byte Pointer to be declared as `ByVal pSignature Long` and then calling it using `varPtr(abSig(0)`

But your code looks fine - I'm puzzled

> ---

Your declare doesn't match Microsoft API declaration. Not sure if that's by design because Signature is a byte pointer

According to docs

```
LPBYTE, BYTE  will be : *   ByRef Byte
```

Change this (by default arguments are passed ByVal)

```
pbSignature As Byte
```

To this

```
ByRef pbSignature As Byte
```

Comment: Thanks for this. I had understood that the default for VB6 (where the original problem seems to manifest itself) was ByRef but I think there's no harm in being explicit so I'll make all the declarations explicit and see what happens.

Comment: Just changed all the default declarations to ByRef and the failure is exactly the same as before.

Comment: Only pSignature should be ByRef - it's the only pointer. I see you're passsing the first element of byte array - I'll edit my answer above for another call suggestion

Comment: For the avoidance of doubt, declaration now as follows:      Private Declare Function CryptVerifySignature 
    Lib "advapi32.dll" 
        Alias "CryptVerifySignatureA" ( 
            ByVal hHash As Long, 
            ByRef pbSignature As Byte, 
            ByVal dwSigLen As Long, 
            ByVal hPubKey As Long, 
            ByVal sDescription As String, 
            ByVal dwFlags As Long 
                ) As Long

Comment: Tried declaring as ByVal pSignature Long and then calling using varPtr(abSig(0)) but still NTE_BAD_SIGNATURE error.

Comment: Is your VB6 project an exe or ActiveX component?

Comment: Can you check your shortcut to the program to see if anything is checked for compatibility mode?

Comment: It is an exe. No compatibility mode settings apply. At this stage I'd be happy to ignore my example in favour of a `CryptVerifySignature` VB example known to work on a 64-bit Windows 10 system

Comment: Can you download and try the zip inside the zip - it expands to an excel file with a demo example - it doesn't use `CryptVerifySignature` but it does declare other functions with byte pointers (using ByVal bptr Long and VarPtr). Test the demo in Excel on Windows 10 64 bit and let me know if it works (it's supposed to) http://www.vbforums.com/attachment.php?attachmentid=134179&d=1452717363

Comment: But so does all my code except the CryptVerifySignature bit. So I'm not really any further on in identifying the problem.